# vSphere .NET SDK Create_VM With Datastore Cluster

Tags: c#, sdk, vmware, vsphere

I am working through the vSphere Web Client SDK DotNet VMCreate sample and the only piece I have not been able to figure out is how to create Virtual disks on a datastore cluster.

My current infrastructure has four datastores, lets call them DS1, DS2, DS3, and DS4 . DS1 & DS2 are part of a datastore cluster called DC1. Using the code supplied by the sample I am only able to see/use the datastore names and have not been able to figure out how use the cluster.

```
//Get config target of ClusterComputerResource
ConfigTarget configTarget = getConfigTargetForHost(computeResMor);

//Get datastores from config target
VirtualMachineDatastoreInfo[] vdsInfo2 = configTarget.datastore;
```

Array output in debug view:

[image]

I know that using a datastore cluster is possible in powerCLI, but i cannot find any documentation anywhere about how to use it in the .NET web client SDK. Any information is absolutely appreciated!